# Is there a difference between using a custom UITableViewCell vs UITableViewHeaderFooterView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm relatively new to iOS swift, but is there a difference between doing this

```
class MyCustomHeaderSection: UITableViewHeaderFooterView
{
    ...
}

myTableView.register(MyCustomHeaderSection.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "section_header")
```

And the following approach

```
class MyCustomHeaderSection: UITableViewCell
{
    ...
}

myTableView.register(MyCustomHeaderSection.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "section_header")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in terms of UI both will work as header/footers , but `MyCustomHeaderSection: UITableViewHeaderFooterView` is really meant for headers/footers while `class MyCustomHeaderSection: UITableViewCell` is meant for actual content cells of the table